# Как использовать progressBar программно и без использования XML?

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

Есть класс GamePanel, в котором происходит весь игровой процесс. Игра связана с управлением космическим кораблем, у которого есть опр. запас прочности, и хотелось бы визуализировать прочность и ее уменьшение через progressBar

```
   RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(context);
    progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
    progressBar.setProgress(100);
    layout.addView(progressBar);
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос без существенных деталей, проблема не ясна и вам, скорее всего, ничего вразумительного ответить нельзя.

Answer (score 4):

Ну так не проблема, делайте:

```
ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(context);
pb.setProgress(intWithShipDurability);
someContainerView.addView(pb);
```

Comment: сделал так, как вы написали, добавил все это дело в конструктор, но ничего не появилось(

Comment: @En1q0d, к сожалению, хоть мне и удалось вычислить IP вашего компьютера файрвол не дал мне доступа к жёсткому диску и я не смог посмотреть ваш код, чтобы понять где и что вы сделали не так.

Comment: добавил то, что я написал в вопрос)

Comment: @En1q0d, ваш RelativeLayout не добавлен на экран. Добавляйте виджеты в то, что уже на экране есть. Т.е. посмотрите разметку активити, найдите контейнер методом findViewById и в него добавляйте

Comment: а что, если у меня класс без XML activity?У меня все через SurfaceView

Comment: @En1q0d На будущее - в следующий раз это в вопросе и пишите, что вы используете SurfaceView и т.д., ибо тут никто не горит желанием вытягивать из вас информацию